# How to disable pam_mount if no password is provided (i. e. authentication with an ssh-key)?

Tags: 18.04, mount, ssh, pam

I'm using `pam_mount` to automatically mount SMB/CIFS shares on login of a user and this works so far, but when someone authenticates without a password (via ssh-key) the mount fails because there is no password to pass to the mount programm. This will lead to a `Permission denied` error and will count as a failed authentication attempt. The problem is that user accounts are locked after several failed authentication attempts. Therefore if you use a ssh-key you will lock yourself out after some time.

Is there a way to tell PAM to not try to mount something if there is no password provided?

I found on their mailing list that an option `soft_try_pass` should do the trick (https://sourceforge.net/p/pam-mount/mailman/message/19574581/) but this option is not available anymore.

This is on Ubuntu 18.04 with `libpam-mount` version `2.16-3ubuntu0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with our Debian clients in an Active Directory environment. To indicate that the authentication process succeeds through a password, you could set an environment variable and then conditionally mount on that variable during session setup.

Create a modified version of the pam mount config in `/usr/share/pam-configs/libpam-mount-pw-only`:

```
Name: Mount volumes for user (pw auth only)
Default: yes
Priority: 128
Auth-Type: Additional
Auth:
        [success=ok default=2]          pam_exec.so /bin/true
        optional                        pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/pam-authenticate
        optional                        pam_mount.so
Session-Interactive-Only: yes
Session-Type: Additional
Session:
        [success=ok default=1]          pam_exec.so quiet /usr/bin/printenv PAM_AUTHENTICATE
        optional                        pam_mount.so
Password-Type: Additional
Password:
        optional                        pam_mount.so disable_interactive
```

Then create the environment file `echo 'PAM_AUTHENTICATE=TRUE' > /etc/default/pam-authenticate` and run `pam-auth-update` to activate the modified configuration (and deactivate the original configuration).

If a user logs in using ssh keys, you will see `pam_exec(sshd:session): /usr/bin/printenv failed: exit code 1` (i.e. `PAM_AUTHENTICATE` not set) in `/var/log/auth.log` instead of the failed mount attempt.

---

Note: sshd will still call `pam_setcred()` and parse the `auth` stack if ssh keys are used. However, `pam_exec.so` will only be executed for `pam_authenticate()` (see [pam_exec - call an external command](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html)) so that we can make the distinction here for a key-based authentication.

This is only a workaround. I would prefer a volume-specific option for `pam_mount.conf.xml` to indicate that no attempt should be performed to mount the volume without a password.